# Cheerio not found with Webpack within module

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webpack, cheerio

I'm using the **scrape-it** module: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/scrape-it

I'm trying to bundle my js with **webpack**. However, I'm encountering this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/scrape-it/~/cheerio/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./package in /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio
resolve file
```

Full stack trace:

```
ERROR in ./~/scrape-it/~/cheerio-req/~/cheerio/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./package in /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio
resolve file
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package doesn't exist
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.webpack.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.web.js doesn't exist
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.js doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package]
[/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.webpack.js]
[/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.web.js]
[/Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio-req/node_modules/cheerio/package.js]
 @ ./~/scrape-it/~/cheerio-req/~/cheerio/index.js 11:18-38
```

I'm kind of confused for why this is occurring since all the appropriate modules exist. **Here's my webpack.config.js file which is probably the source of the issue.**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js']
    },
    node: {
        console: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
}
```

**Why is this occurring? How can this be resolved?**

Comment: Did you forget to `npm install` first? Do you see a `package.json` if you run `ls -lAh /Users/Spicycurryman/Desktop/Main/styell/node_modules/scrape-it/node_modules/cheerio` ?

Comment: @SethHolladay yes I do see it. And no I did not forget to npm install. :/ What else can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had to add `'.json'` to resolve.extensions.

I'm now getting an unrelated error though:

[Using Webpack with Mongoose - mongoose.model is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004659/using-webpack-with-mongoose-mongoose-model-is-not-a-function)